# Global function vs Angular-factory function - memory consumption when added to a global variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, global-variables

I would like to understand the consequences of the following scenario:

```js
var globalVar = {};
_v.func = function (event) {    
                function content...
          };


WrappMainApp.factory('FactoryName', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {

    Some angular factory code...

    var func = function (event) {    
                function content...
          };
    
    globalVar.func = func;
}
```

My question is, is it recommended - memory wise to add a factory function to a global variable, and when doing so, does the function reference carry the rest of the angular app references as well?

Comment: Never ever use a global variable. This is the most pain in every application, it can be overwritten and it's exposed in your whole application. If you wanna have some global things or you wanna save some functions/variables over page-switches, use factories/services.

Comment: Thanks for the response, yes I am trying to avoid it as much as I can. but couldn't figure our the correct solution.